# using dict comprehension if/else logic to determine using a function or not

Tags: python, dictionary-comprehension

I had a broken function that should either wring all items through a function, or only run items that pass `True` from a qualifying function, if a qualifying function is given

```
def transform_dictionary(dictionary, callback, qualification_callback=None):
    return {k: callback(v) if qualification_callback and qualification_callback(v) else v for k, v in dictionary.items()}
```

It was broke because it required the second function to transform. I now have

```
def transform_dictionary(dictionary, callback, qualification_callback=None):
    if qualification_callback:
        return {k: callback(v) if qualification_callback(v) else v for k, v in dictionary.items()}
    else:
        return {k: callback(v) for k, v in dictionary.items()}
```

which is ugly but works. Can I do this in one line, where I either run all values through the callback, or check for truth in the second callback first and only run things that pass? Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a constant function as the default value instead of `None`:

```
def transform_dictionary(dictionary, callback, qc=lambda x: True):
    return {k: callback(v) if qc(v) else v for k, v in dictionary.items()}
```

Comment: oh, so qc always returns true, and it always runs but by default it just gets ignored. very pythony, ty

Answer (score 6):

`v` is only returned if there is a qualification callback and it returns False for the given value, so we can check for this condition and either return `v` if both conditions hold or else return `callback(v)`.

```
def transform_dictionary(dictionary, callback, qualification_callback=None):
    return {k: v if qualification_callback and not qualification_callback(v) else callback(v) 
            for k, v in dictionary.items()}
```

Comment: I think you want `{k : v if ...}`